# Different views for Desktop and mobile Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, mobile

In the application i am developing, it needs entirely two different views for Desktop and Mobile. Not possible using CSS as content is entirely different.

**What I have done?**

I had checked whether it is Desktop/Mobile in *`Routing file`* using code `const isMobile = window.innerWidth < 768;`

And in path component: `component: isMobile ? MobileComponent : DesktopComponent`

This is working perfectly in development environment. But while production build this fails `ng serve --prod` (obviously Angular 5)

**Issue:**

No errors at all, According to `isMobile` true/false it should load MobileComponent/ DesktopComponent. But it does not load even if isMobile is true/false

Always loads MobileComponent in both Desktop & Mobile. while `isMobile` value is getting calculated correctly, `true` for `Mobile` and `false` for `Desktop`

I think the reason is the routes are getting compile already before sending to client.

**Workaround tried but not working:**

Used a if..else condition, while calculating `isMobile` and giving that variable (component) instead of ternary operation in Routing file

**Any way:**

Is there any way I can use to achieve the same functionality?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the error in AOT ?

Comment: @Dhyey no errors at all, Just loading `MobileComponent` even when isMobile is true/false

Comment: have you tried "window.screen.width"

Comment: @shanths isMobile is getting calculated correctly, the ternary operation is not working correctly `component: isMobile ? MobileComponent : DesktopComponent` always returning `MobileComponent `

Comment: but for me it works in production [demo link](http://demo.xerago.com/website/CitiIndia/2017/CMS/Newfolder/dist/)

Comment: @shanths link should be authenticated

Comment: Did you try with a "CanActivate" guard. You could make a "MobileGuard" and "DesktopGuard" that redirect to the other route if it can't display correctly for the current device.

Comment: I fixed some issues on my running example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I said in the question comment section, route guards would be a good solution for this purpose.

The `MobileGuard` would look like this :

```
export class MobileGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private _router: Router, private _mobileService: MobileService) {}

    canActivate(): boolean {
        const isMobile = this._mobileService.isMobile();
        if(!isMobile) {
            this._router.navigate(['/desktop']);
        }
        return isMobile;
    }
}
```

The same for the `DesktopGuard`.

The user trying to access any of the routes, would be redirected to the right one.

[Here is a running example with this suggested solution.](https://mobile-desktop-routing-guards.stackblitz.io)

[And here is the stackblitz editable version.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mobile-desktop-routing-guards)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I will try it out

Answer (score 10):

Don't use canActivate or route guards, because they need to be used for authentication etc.

New way:

```
{
    path: 'your-path',
    loadChildren: () => {
      if(window.innerWidth > 768 ) {
        return import('./your-desktop.module').then(m => m.YourDesktopModule)
      } else {
        return import('./your-mobile.module').then(m => m.YourMobileModule)
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I agree with @CarbonDry that using a logic in your RoutingModule is the best way.
However I think using window size is a poor way to detect device type. Of course, it depends on the use case - if you simply need to show different UI for small screens, `window.innerWidth` will do. If you want separate functionality for mobiles, it might not be just enough.

There are various ways you could check for device type, for example you can use `navigator.orientation === undefined` to check if a device is desktop (because desktops do not support `navigator.orientation`.

Lastly, you could always use `UserAgent` detection. For that, refer to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/13819253/8775880

So in the end, your code might look like this

```
const isDesktop(): boolean => {
   return navigator.orientation === undefined;
}

{
    path: 'path',
    loadChildren: () => {
      if(isDesktop())
        return import('./desktop.module').then((m) => m.DesktopModule);
      return import('./mobile.module').then((m) => m.MobileModule);
    }
}
```

**Edit**
Keep in mind, however, that `loadChildren` will run only once when the path is loaded for the first time. So again, you might want to consider simply checking the screen dimensions. Let's say that `768px` works for portrait on phone, but what if I open the site in landscape mode? In some situations, even landscape mode requires mobile UI. But if you only check client width, you will get desktop version.

Answer (score 5):

Directly make changes in the routes like this -

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component:  window.screen.width > 767 ? WelcomeDesktopComponent : WelcomeMobileComponent
}];
```